# can not add data in sql server database in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, angularjs, model-view-controller

I Have simple app in Angularjs and I have little experience in Angularjs.
my question  is I can add data in database . I think I have no errors that prevent me from adding that data.

There no errors displayed but the data not send correctly

**GoverController**

```
    public ActionResult Index(Governorate gov)
    {
        string message = "";
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (DoctorEntities dc = new Models.DoctorEntities())
            {
                dc.Governorates .Add(gov);
                dc.SaveChanges();
                message = "تم اضافة المحافظة";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            message = "خطا";
        }
        return new JsonResult { Data = message, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };

    }
```

**gov.js**

```
(function () {
angular.module('MyApp', [])
.controller('AdminController', function ($scope, RegisterService) {
    $scope.submitText = "save";
    $scope.submitted = false;
    $scope.message = '';
    $scope.isFormValid = false;
    $scope.gov = {
        GovernorateName: ''
    };
    $scope.$watch('f1.$valid', function (newValue) {
        $scope.isFormValid = newValue;
    });
    $scope.SaveDate = function (data) {
        if (submitText == "save") {
            $scope.submitted = true;
            $scope.message = '';
        }
        if ($scope.isFormValid==false){
            $scope.submitText = "please wait....";
            $scope.gov = data;

            RegisterService.SaveFoemData($scope.gov).then(function (d) {
                alert(d);
                if (d == 'success') {clearform(); }$scope.submitText='save';
            }   );
        }
        else{
            $scope.message='please fill required data';
        }
    };
    function clearform(){
        $scope.gov=null;
        $scope.f1.$setPristine();
        $scope.submitted=false;
    }})
.factory('RegisterService', function ($http,$q) {
    var fac = {};
    fac.SaveFoemData = function (data) {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        $http({
            url: '/Gover/Index',
            method: 'get',
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            headers: {'content-type':'application/json'}

        }).success(function (d) {
            defer.resolve(d);
        }).error(function (e) {
            defer.reject(e);
        });
        return defer.promise();
    }
    return fac;
});
```

})();

**AddGov.cshtml**

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "AddGov";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>AddGov</h2>




<div ng-controller="AdminController">
<form novalidate name="f1" ng-submit="SaveData(gov)">

  {{message}}
  <table>
      <tr>
          <td>
              <input type="text" ng-model="gov.GovernorateName"       name="GovernorateName" ng-class="submitted?'ng-dirty':''" required autofocus />

          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td><input type="submit" value="{{submitText}}" /></td>


      </tr>
   </table>

  </form>
  </div>


 @section scripts{
 <script src="~/Scripts/MyProject/gov.js"></script>
  }
```

i tried to find solution to this question